# How to merge two Content Type Hub from different farm?

Tags: content-type-hub

We have two SharePoint 2013 on-premise farms and are planning to merge them. The bad thing is, each of the farm host a Content Type Hub and one of custom content type "Classification" is duplicated.

Is it possible to merge them? If not, can I safely remove one content type hub before merge? Any guide or reference is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Their is no OOTB way to merge the two Content Type Hub. Rather you can think about manually moving the Content type from one Farm to other and then republish them.

check these resources for more idea:

http://www.balestra.be/2012/09/content-type-hub-limitations-in-sharepoint-2010.html

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn197167.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: In the balestra article it mentioned "You can have more then 1 CT hub". But I need to create a new Managed Metadata service application to link with 2nd CT hub, right?

Comment: Correct, you have one CT Hub with each MMS applications.